# Incorporating Treant.js into a Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, external, require

I am trying to incorporate the Treant.js library in my Vue app in order to generate a tree diagram from a JSON data object. Here are my import statements in my main view...

```
import Vue from "vue"
import store from "../../store"
import { getWebSocket } from "../../services/util.js"
import '../../assets/css/Treant.css'
import '../../assets/scripts/raphael'

var Treant = require("../../assets/scripts/Treant")
```

and here is where I attempt to call the Treant constructor (this.localTrace.route is the JSON object) ...

```
  var tree = new Treant(this.localTrace.route, function() {alert('Tree Loaded')})
```

When I try to launch the page, I receive an error that states "Treant is not a constructor", and the app fails to build the tree.

CONVERSELY

I attempted to import the library globally in my main.js file like so...

```
import "./assets/scripts/raphael"
import "./assets/scripts/Treant"
```

When I do it this way, Vue can make its way into the Treant.js code, but then gives me this error instead

```
this._R.setSize is not a function
at Tree.handleOverflow (Treant.js?e3b3:842)
at Tree.positionNodes (Treant.js?e3b3:768)
at Tree.positionTree (Treant.js?e3b3:512)
at new Treant (Treant.js?e3b3:2164)
```

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time and you probably found a solution, but just for other guys visiting this tread:
open your main.js Vue initialization file and add:

```
import Raphael from "raphael"

window.Raphael = Raphael
```

Now Treant will be able to use Raphael correctly.